# Assigning values in a predicate

Tags: prolog

Is there a way to assing 2 times a different value in a variable inside a predicate?For example can we somehow make

```
X is 10,
X is 3.
```

produce true?

Comment: No. Prolog variables are single-assignment. They can be unbound and rebound through backtracking but do not allow yourself to be confused into thinking that this is like reassigning a variable in an imperative language.

Comment: Also, Prolog does not *assign* variables. It operates under a principle of *unification of terms*. The `is/2` operator, in particular, is used for evaluating arithmetic expressions and attempting to bind (unify) that result with the variable first argument. In Prolog logic, once a variable is bound, it cannot be re-bound except through backtracking.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't do it like this. `is/2` is for evaluating arithmetic expressions.

Without any context whatsoever it is <s>difficult</s> impossible to suggest what is the right way to do it. The traditional way is to have a predicate that looks like this:

```
ten_or_three(10).
ten_or_three(3).
```

You can do all kinds of Prolog-y things with a predicate like that.

```
?- ten_or_three(10).
true.

?- ten_or_three(4).
false.

?- length(L, 3), maplist(ten_or_three, L), sumlist(L, Sum).
L = [10, 10, 10],
Sum = 30 ;
L = [10, 10, 3],
Sum = 23 ;
L = [10, 3, 10],
Sum = 23 ;
L = [10, 3, 3],
Sum = 16 ;
L = [3, 10, 10],
Sum = 23 ;
L = [3, 10, 3],
Sum = 16 ;
L = [3, 3, 10],
Sum = 16 ;
L = [3, 3, 3],
Sum = 9.
```

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```
p(X) :- X is 3;X is 5.
```

is true of `X = 3` or `5`.

Comment: At the very least, use unification instead of `is`.